# How to EnableProxyTypes on a service accessed from the IWorkflowContext in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a C# workflow that I'm trying to create an `IOrganzationService` in that has the proxy types enabled on it so I can use my early bound data types...

This is how I'm creating the `IOrganizationSerivce`

```
IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
```

But since I don't have an `OrganizationServiceProxy` object, I can't call EnableProxyTypes() on the service, and any create calls on the service using an early bound entity fails.

I know I can revert to setting the server url url, sdk server url, and organization in the app.config and use that to create an `OrganizationServiceProxy` but it seems like I should be able to just set the EnableProxyTypes on the IOrganizationService that I already have...

### Update

I believe this was a bug in 2011 and maybe 2013 that has long since been resolved.  See Jim's answer with a link as to why you should not be using the accepted answer for 2015 or newer instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use the early bound entities in the context of an workflow try the following snippet:

```
IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();

var type = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.SynchronousRuntime.WorkflowContext, Microsoft.Crm.Workflow, Version=5.0.0.0");
type.GetProperty("ProxyTypesAssembly").SetValue(serviceFactory, typeof(YourServiceContext).Assembly, null); //YourServiceContext - the name of crm context
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);
```

As you can see there is a property named `ProxyTypesAssembly` that specifies the assembly where you keep the early bound entities. The only way i could set this property was using reflection because the `WorkflowContextBase` (the base class of `WorkflowContext`) was not accessible.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!  I'm surprised this isn't a little more documented...

Comment: This appears to be broken in CRM 2013, `type` is null. Have you come across a work around?

Comment: @AntSwift see my new answer, below, for the CRM 2013+ fix

Comment: It is essential that anyone who used this workaround remove it. It is no longer necessary and will cause the workflow activity to break.
More information: [Remove unsupported code that uses reflection in custom workflow activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/best-practices/business-logic/remove-unsupported-code-using-reflection-workflow-activities)

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post, addressing an issue that was fixed long ago. But some of the workarounds provided here are not supported and will cause workflow activities that have used them to break.

Please see this: [Remove unsupported code that uses reflection in custom workflow activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/best-practices/business-logic/remove-unsupported-code-using-reflection-workflow-activities)

Answer (score 2):

The fix for CRM 2013 (and beyond, I hope), is the much simpler:

```
IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();

// this is the important change
var property = serviceFactory.GetType().GetProperty("ProxyTypesAssembly");

property.SetValue(serviceFactory, typeof(YourServiceContext).Assembly, null);
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);
```

Comment: You're able to use reflection in a sandbox environment, as long as you don't access something you wouldn't normally have access to.  So you can reflectively call a public method, but not a private one

Answer (score 2):

The answers using reflection are not ideal, you will not be able to register your assembly in sandbox isolation mode.

You can add the following to the end of your AssemblyInfo.cs file in the Plugin or Workflow project.

```
[assembly: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ProxyTypesAssembly()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this same issue couple months back. 
The issue you are experiencing is due to the inconsistencies in the api.

The OrganizationServiceProxy  implements IOrganizationService which only has a few members create, update etc. It also inherits from ServiceProxy with members ClientCredentials, IsAuthenticated, DeviceCredentials etc.

Now what you don't find on the interface or the abstract base class is the EnableProxyTypes member.

So basically your outta luck. I ended using concrete OrganizationServiceProxy.

have a look here and do the comparison for yourself.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice_members.aspx, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy.aspx, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg306039.aspx
and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy_methods.aspx

Guess the ms crm dev team creating the api should have used tdd and a mocking framework to pick it up early in development.

Cheers
Rustin